# Colouring Filtered Results and copying over, minus the header

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

Im trying to filter my data by month and by invoiced and then colour the results and copy them over to a seperate tab at the bottom of the data, it all works but it seems to colour every row below my data making the copying a lot slower and it also seems to copy over the header, is there any way to only colour the rows with data and not copy over the header?

```
   Sub FILTERING()

    strInput = InputBox("Please Enter the Month you are Analysing in the following format: Jan-20 (No Spaces)")
    ActiveSheet.Range("Y1:Y1").AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:=strInput

     ActiveSheet.Range("A:AK").AutoFilter Field:=29, Criteria1:= _
        "=INVOICED"
        Purpley = RGB(228, 223, 236)
    Range("A:AK").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = Purpley

    Dim lastRow As Long
    With Sheets("Data")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
    Range("A:AK").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 
    Destination:=Sheets("Data").Cells(lastRow, "A")

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub FILTERING()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, strInput As String
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
    lastR = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
      
    strInput = InputBox("Please Enter the Month you are Analysing in the following format: Jan-20 (No Spaces)")
    ActiveSheet.Range("Y1:Y1").AutoFilter field:=25, Criteria1:=strInput

     ActiveSheet.Range("A:AK").AutoFilter field:=29, Criteria1:= _
        "=INVOICED"
        Purpley = RGB(228, 223, 236)
    Range("A2:AK" & lastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = Purpley

    Dim lastRow As Long
    With Sheets("Data")
        lastRow = .cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
    Range("A1:AK" & lastR).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                       Destination:=Sheets("Data").cells(lastRow, "A")
    End Sub
```